# Website Block's IP address using some browsers and downloader crawlers

Tags: configuration, ip-address, blocked-services, web-proxy, ip-address-leak

How does some websites knows that we are using onion browser.
Some of the online shopping websites won't even let in to enter using the tor browser? How is this possible?

For instance take this below picture as examples

[image]

[image]

How should we configure the tor browser even though tor censors are enabled?
How do we encrypt all the information passing through the nodes, just like as an VPN?

Is it possible to achieve 
IP + SSL = ?

Comment: the IP-addesses of exit-nodes are public and hence can be blocked... https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#HideExits

Comment: Running a VPN on Whonix custom Workstation, your exit node will from VPN which can be recognized by website.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the website you are trying to access is aware that your IP address that you appear to be from is actually a Tor exit node.  This would tell the website that you are using Tor.

/Matthew Campbell

Comment: Then how are we suppose to browse from the TOR?... Do you got any idea!

Comment: I was reading another question that said we could use a vpn service before connecting to the Tor network.  I'm still waiting for an answer on that one.  See: My ISP is blocking Tor.  Once this is answered I'll be able to use a vpn with antiDPI or SSL VPN api access to evade my ISP's firewall.